# how to handle an array with filter().map in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I'm trying to make a search engine for my database.
I start with mapping all the elements and then I have a filter for some of the things in each elements like this:

```
const filteredCars = (carsGet.filter(item => {
        const filter = (item.make.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.make.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) === '')
            && (item.year > min || min === '') 
            && (item.year < max || max === '')
            && (item.color === color || color === '');
        console.log(filter);
        return filter
        
        }))
```

The filter works fine as long as it's just one item, but as soon as I send an array to color it returns false, if I set initialState to color: [] and change color === '' to color === [] they return false from start.

I have created a handler for the color:

```
handleChange (e) {
    var options = e.target.options;
    
    var value = [];
    for (var i = 0, l = options.length; i < l; i++) {
      if (options[i].selected) {
        value.push(options[i].value);
      }
    }
    console.log(value)
    this.setState({color: value});
  }
```

The console.log returns ["guld", "red"] but the filter returns false for all elements even if i only select one color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `color` is an array or a string and return a boolean accordingly.

```
const filteredCars = (carsGet.filter(item => {
    const checkColor = () => {
        if(Array.isArray(color)) {
            return (color.length === 0) || color.includes(item.color);
        } else {
            return (color === '') || (color === item.color);
        }
    }

    const filter = (item.make.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) ||
        item.make.toLowerCase().includes(searchfield.toLowerCase()) === '')
        && (item.year > min || min === '')
        && (item.year < max || max === '')
        && checkColor();
    console.log(filter);
    return filter

}))
```